# nodejs - iso 3166 - Alternative countries names

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, dictionary, iso-3166

I'm writing a program that extracts countries from https://restcountries.eu/
I'm using the data to save in my mongo DB and update it.
ofc, the data doesn't change too often, but this is for a decade forward.

```
const COUNTRIES_URL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';
const axios = require('axios');

exports.httpCrawl = () => (
  axios.get(COUNTRIES_URL).then(response => (
    response.data.map(country => ({
      name: country.name,
      digits2: country.alpha2Code,
      digits3: country.alpha3Code,
      countryId: country.numericCode,
      flag: country.flag
    })))));
```

now when the data is in the DB, I want to use it to map other entities I'm getting from other APIs, for example, sports games. but the games come with the country's alternative name (for example England instead of Great Britain).

Is there a way to map the country's alternative names to the iso 3166 name/id?

Comment: Are you basically asking if there's a service you can get a country's ISO3166 name using their alternative name?

Comment: @James more asking if someone tackled this question before. I'm sure I'm not the first to deal with alternative names. if there is a service/package/API for this, great. if there is a closed list of all the common alternative names, cool as well

Comment: there are plenty of sources for pulling country lists, your particular case though is specific in that you need to map the alternative names (I wouldn't necessarily say that's a common requirement). You would probably need to leverage something like [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) to perform a fuzzy search, rather than something that has a straight 1:1 mapping.

Comment: @James that's a great idea, i'll try it out and update here

Comment: @James this worked far better than I hoped for! I want to accept this solution

Comment: excellent, glad I could help. I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage a service like [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro), this would allow you to pull associated country information based on alternative name or partial information.